# How to pass dataset out of a proc in TCL

Tags: parameters, return, tcl

I'm reading a set of data line by line from a file in a procedure. Now how can I return these lines of data from this procedure. And how can I assign these data outputted from this procedure to a dataset?

```
proc readdata{} {
    set fptr [open Test1.txt r]
    set fptr_data [read $fptr]
    set data [split $fptr_data "\n"]  
}
```

How can I return this data from this procedure?

Comment: What is a "dataset" in your case, precisely?

Comment: You probably want to `close $fptr` between the `read` and the `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [return](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/return.htm) statement:

```
proc readdata {filename} {
    set fptr [open $filename r]
    set fptr_data [read $fptr]
    set data [split $fptr_data "\n"]
    return $data
}
...
set dataset [readdata Test1.txt]
```

However, by default Tcl procedures return the result of the last command that was run. Personally I prefer an explicit `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you need do nothing else:

> When a procedure is invoked, the procedure's return value is the value specified in a `return` command. If the procedure does not execute an explicit `return`, then its return value is *the value of the last command executed* in the procedure's body.

-- http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/proc.htm